# Получить объект (Django ORM)

Tags: python, django, orm

Я могу достучаться до значения следующим образом:

```py
In [1]: DictionaryItem.objects.get(pk='efb3b7e8-3f2f-4a92-8a00-5f3815a5bbc0').value.all()[0].view_value                                                                                       
Out[1]: '14:00'
```

Как мне получить этот объект DictionaryItem? Т.е. что должно быть в конструкции

```py
DictionaryItem.objects.get(???='14:00')
```

Comment: Не совсем понял как выглядит модель DictionaryItem. Но по идее на месте "???" должно быть указанно поле модели хранящее этот атрибут.

Comment: Я в первом листинге указал путь к значению. Т. е. в атрибуте `value` хранится менеджер, возвращающий кверисет, в первом и единственом значении которого и храниться нужное значение.
Мне не понятно, как пройти через этот кверисет.

Comment: Попробуй использовать связку filter + Q  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) Вот ссылка на документацию